# Update Launcher Icon in the Application List after updating desktop file exec and icon (without restart/relogin)

Tags: gnome, icons, launcher, .desktop

Let's create the following file:

```
> $ cat ~/.local/share/applications/testing.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=firefox
Icon=firefox
```

After that, we will have a new Firefox icon in the Applications list.

Let's now change the file to run another executable and to have a different icon:

```
> $ cat ~/.local/share/applications/testing.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Test
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-calculator
Icon=gnome-calculator
```

For some reason, the icon doesn't change, and it continues to run Firefox. Restarting PC helps to update the icon. `update-icon-caches -f` and `update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications` don't help.

The question is: is there some way to actualize the icon in the launcher without PC restart? Probably some other command?

Answer (score 0):

Normal behavior is that updates in a `.desktop` launcher are reflected in the Applications Overview seconds after the update. Note that an update happens when opening the Applications overview. Thus, the Applications Overview will *not* update while it is already open. If you still see the old icon, close then reopen the Applications overview.

If it does not update, logging out then back in will certainly cause the update.

Comment: Thanks. The question is: can I somehow force update it without re-login?

Comment: @SerVB: that is not correct. Currently the question is " is there some way to actualize the icon in the launcher without PC restart? " Feel free to correct your question (use "edit").